# need help passing variables into $(#something).submit(function(e){

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm new to jQuery and am having a couple problems with this code:

```
var theCommentId = '';
var buildFormName = '';

$('.comment_submit').bind('click', function() {
    theCommentId = $(this).attr('this_id');
    buildFormName = ('#AddMessageForm_' + theCommentId);
}); 

alert(buildFormName);
```

This returns '#AddMessageForm_1' (or 2 or 234 depending on what button is clicked). That part is working great.

But then I need to pass `buildFormName` in here so I can process multiple forms with different names. The form names are generated dynamically from an id number that's appended to addMessageForm

```
$(buildFormName).submit(function(e) {
    // process form data here...
    $.post('process.php', $(this).serialize(), function(msg) {
    }
```

The above returns no errors, but `$this` is empty and I can't create the db row from an empty `$this`! it works if I don't try to pass the variable `buildFormName` in there. example:

```
$('#addMessageForm_1').submit(function(e) {
    // process form data here...
    $.post('process.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){
    }
```

That works fine. Ii'm hoping that I'm missing something simple here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you calling `$(buildFormName).submit(function(e){`?  Inside of the `click` function?

Comment: Just to clarify: is it AddMessageForm with a capital "A" or addMessageForm with a lowercase "a"? Casing will affect your IDs.

Comment: If you remove the brackets when setting `buildFormName` does that help? They aren't necessary and it may not be helping...

Comment: Not sure why this is happening, but try using `e.target` instead of `this`, see if that helps.

Comment: it's inside of $(document).ready(function(){ }

Comment: i removed the brackets for buildFormName. same output for the variable. didn't solve the problem though. and sorry about the caps. it's a lowercase 'a'... i just typed it wrong in here... they do match up on the actual code... and whoa! i just replaced this with e.target and that did the trick. you guys rock!!#@$ thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You should crate a submit handler as a separate function and then use it. Try this.

```
$('.comment_submit').bind('click',function(){
    theCommentId = $(this).attr('this_id');

    buildFormName = ('#AddMessageForm_' + theCommentId);

    $(buildFormName).submit(formSubmitHandler);
}); 

function formSubmitHandler(){
   // process form data here...

   $.post('process.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){

   }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain this? I don't see much difference between a named function and an anonymous one...

Comment: That is because if you use anonymous function they are not part of a closure.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `this` with `e.target`, see if that helps.

```
$(buildFormName).submit(function(e) {
    // process form data here...
    $.post('process.php', $(e.target).serialize(), function(msg) {
}
```